# How do I make the Windows search window flush with the left side of my screen?

Tags: windows-10

I use the Windows search window a lot. I hit the Windows key, start typing and get my result. It seems like some while ago, an indent was suddenly added to the search menu, as shown in the picture. I marked it in red. Maybe I did something wrong with an unlucky keystroke or click.

How do I make this window flush with the left side of the screen again?

[image]

Comment: It's unlikely there is a way.  There may be a way via the registry, but it's unlikely since Microsoft heavily integrated the UI for the universal applications (store apps) into the Windows UI in Windows 10 _(much more so than in Windows 8)_, rendering many of the registry edits for the Windows UI not customizable (keys may still be there, but changing them has no effect).

Comment: I see, thanks! The search bar has never looked this way however. It has only started looking this way since a few weeks; were there any updates that changed this? I have two other Win10 machines that don't have this indentation which are up-to-date.

Comment: Mine has the indentation, so it could be this was apart of the bi-annual 1909 update.   Windows Update won't always show bi-annual updates and will list an older version as still being up to date.  If you're sure each are on v1909, someone else will need to chime in.  If you're not sure: **`WinKey` + `R`** > Open: `winver` > OK

Comment: I'm gonna try that, thanks for the comprehensive comments :-)

Comment: It shows lined up here on two V1909 machines and one V2004 machine. I cannot see any setting that changes that. You can try running DISM (dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth followed by SFC /SCANNOW.  Use an Admin Command prompt. I am not sure these repairs will fix this issue